# Magento admin checkout problem

Tags: php, checkout, sales-order, magento-1.6

I have a weird problem regarding a order checkout form the back end section. I have a product that is not is stock.
It has 0 qty, no back-orders, and the out of stock status.

When i try to make an order with this product, surprisingly the order goes throw with no issues causing the stock qty to become -1.

I would like to stop an admin from making an order if the product is not in stock.

This behavior was tested on Magento 1.6.2.0.

Any help regarding this issue would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Installed a fresh instance of magento 1.6.2.0 and it has the same behaviour.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?